# Otimização de query SQL-SERVER

Tags: sql-server

Preciso obter o campo `EMISSION_DATE` da  `TLX_VENDA` e o campo `B9_DATA` da tabela `TLX_ESTOQUE_INI`, porém preciso fazer isso dentro do `OUTER APPLY`. 
Eu consegui chegar no resultado porém está muito lento.

Segue abaixo a última `query` que fiz:

```
    SELECT  FN.COMPANY,
            FN.FILIAL,
            FN.DOC, 
            FN.SERIE,
            FN.TIPONF,
            NF.NFORI,
            ESTORNO,        
            PRODUTO,
            P.DESCR,        
            FN.LOCAL,   
            ISNULL (A2.A2_COD,A1_COD) [COD CLIENTE],
            ISNULL (A2.A2_NOME,A1_NOME) [NOME CLIENTE],
        --  ISNULL (A2.A2_NOME,A1_NOME) [NOME CLIENTE], 
        --  TM,     
            FN.ORIGEM,      
            NF.XXOPER,
        --  QUANT,      
            FN.NUMSERI,     
        --  V.EMISSION_DATE,
        --  E.B9_DATA
            R.B9_DATA,
            VE.EMISSION_DATE,
            CAST(CONCAT(DATA, ' ', HRINI) AS DATETIME) DT,
    --      DATAFIM,
            CASE FN.FLAG_TM WHEN 'E' THEN 'ENTRADA' WHEN 'S' THEN 'SAIDA' END AS FLAG       
            FROM TLX_INVENTORY_TRANS_HIST FN 
    LEFT JOIN TLX_PRODUTOS_INFO P WITH (NOLOCK)
            ON P.COD = FN.PRODUTO
    LEFT JOIN TLX_NFI_ENTRADASAIDA NF WITH (NOLOCK)
            ON NF.COMPANY = FN.COMPANY 
            AND NF.FILIAL = FN.FILIAL 
            AND NF.DOC = FN.DOC 
            AND NF.SERIE = FN.SERIE AND NF.NUMSEQ = FN.NUMSEQ   
            AND NF.COD = FN.PRODUTO AND NF.FLAG = FN.FLAG_TM
    LEFT JOIN SA1010 A1  WITH (NOLOCK)
            ON A1_COD = FN.CLIFOR 
            AND A1_LOJA = FN.LOJA 
            AND A1.D_E_L_E_T_ = '' 
            AND (
                (FN.FLAG_TM = 'S' AND FN.TIPO NOT IN ('B', 'D')) 
                OR (FN.FLAG_TM = 'E' AND FN.TIPO IN ('B', 'D'))
            ) 
    LEFT JOIN  SA2010 A2  WITH (NOLOCK)
            ON A2_COD = FN.CLIFOR 
            AND A2_LOJA = FN.LOJA 
            AND A2.D_E_L_E_T_ = '' 
            AND (
               (FN.FLAG_TM = 'S' AND FN.TIPO IN ('B', 'D')) 
               OR (FN.FLAG_TM = 'E' AND FN.TIPO NOT IN ('B', 'D'))
            ) 
  OUTER APPLY (
               SELECT B9_COD,B9_DATA 
               FROM TLX_ESTOQUE_INI AS E 
               WHERE E.COMPANY = FN.COMPANY 
               AND E.B9_FILIAL = FN.FILIAL 
               AND E.B9_COD = FN.PRODUTO
   ) AS R
   OUTER APPLY (
               SELECT EMISSION_DATE 
               FROM TLX_VENDAS AS V     
               WHERE V.COMPANY = FN.COMPANY 
               AND V.SITE = FN.FILIAL 
               AND  V.SERIAL_NO = FN.NUMSERI 
               AND V.PART_NO = FN.PRODUTO
   ) AS VE
   WHERE FN.LOCAL IN ('17','18') 
   AND FN.NUMSERI IN ('46774197','41206809','26831647','2925','41552704','42825514','45893206','3528','46774208','42963745','48137580','41601079','41210287','3015192','48860830','44179326','47910283','48031190','48687321','45923658','47962949','49318825','40802021','46618247','47752985','46444583','44104175','46444470','43378548','28297475','47701660','23088358','43381319','23352097','46774677','4822','4703','47881900','47881175','47728987','48318326','47680861','46427019','40401425','44341744','44341745','48521742','27284199','46106793','46103491','47215205','46106792','46106764','46103628','46103712','46103627','47385562','46106710','46103588','46106755','46106744','46106732','44763863','27077336','26994715','40688897','42571588','26698791','46106745','46106708','46106763','46103701','46103625','46106718','26831254','47383688','46106719','46103431','46103429','26690540','46080142','28180776','40720771','28210636','41394485','46559885','46560735',   '46566134','27475370','46561815','17206014','41306310','28014050','28193191','45625293','44561283','26753448','26754226','15557861','19489152','47373318','47781575','42769992','44969218','43422275','42772450','45335787','44278083','44272414','44054486','27920321','45106301','48430893','49283529','48978523','48569659','48573357','48125550','25825863','28036290','25319734','25280187','26337586','26192567','26261904','43799292','26598096','25761297','25749913','25825930','25749477','45470401',    '25259627','25092311','47223168','47109181','47588116','47587625','47587038','666874','689435','692731','637409','680056','691476','692735','691523','691481','445948','691498','691486','27108831','27585283','27585126','27108132','27901937','27941437','27941449','27585197','27901951','27916993','27108051','27585103','27902120','27901920','27901903','27107040','27108048','27941436','27901904','102610','106134','106106','2285310')
```

Comment: Se você apertar `ctrl+k` você formatará um bloco de códigos. Você também pode formatar blocos inline deixando o sql entre dois ticks `. Esta ilegível do jeito que você escreveu

Comment: Vou fazer so um momento

Comment: Consegui, acho que agora ficou melhor para poder ve. rs

Comment: seria interessante ter a estrutura do teu banco de dados, pois é dificil te ajudar sem ter esse conhecimento.

Comment: Não posso colocar a estrutura aqui, tem mais ou menos uma ideia de como poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Minha duvida seria na condicao do outer apply, pois a syntax não está incorreta, porque o sql serve roda a query, mas demora muito

Comment: Leonardo a sua pergunta não condiz com sua dúvida, segundo a pergunta eu entendi que você quer buscar somente dois campos de duas tabelas, eu responderia algo assim `SELECT EMISSION_DATE  FROM TLX_VENDA ` por exemplo. Será que você poderia editar a pergunta e expor o seu objetivo com a query e o que está com dificuldade?

Comment: Então Caique eu quero justamente isso.
mas o meu problema esta ocorrendo no outer apply, pois a query nao esta errada, so esta demorando muito, dps q eu fiz o outer apply.
Eu acho que pode está com alguma duplicidade

Comment: Eu quero pegar somente esses 2 campos dessas 2 tabelas, fazendo tudo em uma subquery, pra isso eu usei o outer apply

Comment: Entendido, realmente sem a estrutura vai ficar um pouco complicado te ajudar. Tente acompanhar o plano de execução do sql quando roda a query ele vai conseguir te mostrar os locais que mais custam nela.

Comment: Query ja está rodando a +/- 20 minutos..rs

Answer (score 0):

> *Preciso obter o campo EMISSION_DATE da TLX_VENDA e o campo B9_DATA da tabela TLX_ESTOQUE_INI*

Pelo que solicita, não me parece necessário o uso de APPLY. Sugiro que no lugar de

```
  OUTER APPLY (
               SELECT B9_COD,B9_DATA 
               FROM TLX_ESTOQUE_INI AS E 
               WHERE E.COMPANY = FN.COMPANY 
               AND E.B9_FILIAL = FN.FILIAL 
               AND E.B9_COD = FN.PRODUTO
   ) AS R
   OUTER APPLY (
               SELECT EMISSION_DATE 
               FROM TLX_VENDAS AS V     
               WHERE V.COMPANY = FN.COMPANY 
               AND V.SITE = FN.FILIAL 
               AND  V.SERIAL_NO = FN.NUMSERI 
               AND V.PART_NO = FN.PRODUTO
   ) AS VE
```

utilize

```
   left join TLX_ESTOQUE_INI as R
              on R.COMPANY = FN.COMPANY 
                 and R.B9_FILIAL = FN.FILIAL 
                 and R.B9_COD = FN.PRODUTO
   left join TLX_VENDAS AS VE
              on VE.COMPANY = FN.COMPANY 
                 and VE.SITE = FN.FILIAL 
                 and VE.SERIAL_NO = FN.NUMSERI 
                 and VE.PART_NO = FN.PRODUTO
```

Quanto mais simples, melhor.

---

Com relação a melhorar a performance, após realizar a modificação proposta acima gere o plano de execução e analise-o. Se não tiver conhecimento sobre planos de execução, grave o plano de execução em formato XML e abra outro tópico com link para ele, solicitando apoio na análise do plano de execução.

--
por https://lnkd.in/daWmnx7

Comment: @LeonardoPalmieri Nesse seu caso o APPLY só complica.