# Erro "No column name was specified"

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Alguém poderia me informar o porque desse erro?

> "Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 26 No column name was specified for
>   column 1 of 'A'. Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 42 No column name
>   was specified for column 1 of 'B'."

Segue a query e parte do erro :

```
OUTER APPLY (SELECT CONCAT(TT.NUMSERI,TT.PRODUTO ,MAX(TT.DATA)) 
                FROM TLX_INVENTORY_TRANS_HIST AS TT WITH (NOLOCK)
                    WHERE TT.PRODUTO = FN.PRODUTO AND TT.NUMSERI = FN.NUMSERI
                        GROUP BY TT.NUMSERI,TT.PRODUTO,TT.DATA)AS A

OUTER APPLY (SELECT CONCAT(TT.NUMSERI,TT.PRODUTO ,MIN(TT.DATA)) 
                 FROM TLX_INVENTORY_TRANS_HIST AS  TT WITH (NOLOCK)
                    WHERE TT.PRODUTO = FN.PRODUTO AND TT.NUMSERI = FN.NUMSERI
                        GROUP BY TT.NUMSERI,TT.PRODUTO,TT.DATA)AS B
```

Comment: OUTER APPLY?! Viu a resposta do tópico https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/273763/otimiza%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-query-sql-server ?

Comment: Sim.. mas a onde nesse trecho? 
esse outer apply sao duas subquerys de uma maior

Comment: Pois é, tira esse OUTER APPLY e coloca LEFT JOIN. Fica mais simples. Veja a resposta no tópico vinculado.

Comment: o LEFT JOIN nesse caso nao me atende, eu fiz o teste antes de fazer um outer apply

Answer (score 2):

É necessário que as expressões presentes nas subconsultas sejam denominadas.
Por exemplo:

```
-- código #1
... (SELECT CONCAT(TT.NUMSERI,TT.PRODUTO ,MAX(TT.DATA)) as SERI_PROD_DATA
                FROM TLX_INVENTORY_TRANS_HIST AS TT WITH (NOLOCK)
                    WHERE TT.PRODUTO = FN.PRODUTO AND TT.NUMSERI = FN.NUMSERI
                        GROUP BY TT.NUMSERI,TT.PRODUTO,TT.DATA) as A
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado!
Funcionou, só não entendi muito o do porque

Comment: Funcinou
Mas quando eu as chamo fica dando esse erro :
The multi-part identifier "TT.DATA" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
The multi-part identifier "TT.DATA" could not be bound.

  CAST(TT.DATA AS DATETIME) PRIMEIRA_DATA,  
  CAST(TT.DATA AS DATETIME) SEGUNDA_DATA,

Comment: A subconsulta gerada pelo código #1 possui alias `A`. A mensagem de erro que você transcreveu cita alias `TT` e em um contexto completamente diferente. São erros de origens diferentes; melhor abrir outro tópico para esse novo erro.